# load log4j.xml in springboot project occur an error

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

in my springboot project, i used

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

The log4j2.xml's log level is INFO, and i created log4j2-test.xml file in same path, the log4j2-test.xml's log level is DEBUG.
i discovered during the online process that DEBUG level logs were actually printed. I understand that log4j test. xml is not effective, why?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two phases during a Spring Boot startup:

- in the first phase the native configuration process of your logging backend occurs. For Log4j 2.x it is [described here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) and chooses the `log4j2-test.xml` configuration, hence the `DEBUG` messages,
- in the second phase (as soon as Spring Boot creates an `Environment`) the Spring Boot-specific `logging.config` property is used and `log4j2.xml` is chosen.

To always use `log4j2.xml` just:

- move `log4j2-test.xml` into the test classpath (usually `src/test/resources`),
- remove the `logging.config` property since it just points at the default config file.